# SSRS report - conditional reporting after exporting to excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, formatting, conditional-statements

I have built a SSRS report where I have left the first column of a table empty. I want every cell in this column to be conditionally formatted so that it changes to red fill whenever I type in "r" in one of these cells AFTER exporting it to excel. Can I do this directly in the report builder?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you guys !

Comment: Just to clarify its the Excel's sheet cells that need to change to red and not the SSRS report cells right?

Comment: Hi Emmanuel - thats correct. But I would like to avoid to add conditional formatting manually after exporting the report to excel. I was hoping I can code it in the report builder so that everything is set once I export

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to do it in Excel.